# hibernate issue with left join fetch

Tags: sql, hibernate

I'm trying to get rid of left join fetch in one of our HQLs:

query = select r,f,c from ClassPos r, ClassFal f ,ClassCon c left  join fetch c.ClassReg
where

DB contains this data satisfying above where clause:

ClassPos has 1 row, ClassFal has 2 rows, ClassCon has 1 row and ClassReg has 1 row.

We're using scrollable results to scroll through the results:

```
ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
i =0
while(results.next())
{
i++
}
print(i);
```

We're expecting the resultset to have 2 rows but it's returning 1(i=1). When we run the SQL, we can clearly see 2 rows in the DB.

Now when we get rid of left join fetch, we see the result set has 2 rows:

```
query = select r,f,c from ClassPos r, ClassFal f ,ClassCon c 
where <clause>
```

Tried looking up various places but can't get a reason. Can somebody explain this behaviour?

Comment: Format your code properly, it is difficult to read your post.

Comment: formatted the code. please check now